# Combine and Subtract items from different Collecitons

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

Excuse my ignorance, I am new in MongoDB. I am having tree collections, where the one is a superset of the other two whose elements are not overlapped. Each item is distinguish by a unique string id. What I want is to get the items of the superset that are not included in the other two collections. Could you please provide me some hint on how do do this efficiently?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Superset structure: 
`{ "_id" : 1, "str_id" : "ABC1fd3fsewer", "date": "a day" }`

Subset 1 structure: `{ "_id" : 1, "str_id" : "ABre1fd3fsewer", "description" : "product" }`

Subset 2 structure: `{ "_id" : 1, "str_id" : "ABC1fd3fsewfe"}`

Each collection has a different structure but all have a common filed, the `str_id`.

*EDIT Improved by @Neel suggestion*
I have following format:

```
parent = [{'str_id':'a', 'tag1':'parent_random', 'tag2': 'parent_random', 'tag3':'parent_random'},{'str_id':'b',...},{'str_id':'c',...},{'str_id':'d',...}...]
child1 = [{'str_id':'a', 'tag2': child1_random'},{'str_id':'b', 'tag2': 'child1_random'}]
child2 = [{'str_id':'c', 'tag1':'child2_random'}]
```

and I want

```
outcome = [{'str_id':'c', 'tag1':'parent_random', 'tag2': 'parent_random', 'tag3':'parent_random'},{'str_id':'d', 'tag1':'parent_random', 'tag2': 'parent_random', 'tag3':'parent_random'}]
```

Comment: It will be more comprehensive if you provide a dummy example of the structure of your data and what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: @Neel I made a small edit. What I am interested is the items of superset with `str_id`'s not included in the other two collections, i.e., sunset 1 and 2. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: can you check if what i added in the edit is what you actually want?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need an aggregate operation.

This document might help you:
[Lookup in an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use-lookup-with-an-array)

You can do multiple lookups with one aggregate operation so you can check both the subset collections.

I am going to assume you are working with a REST API and that the client is sending a request for a subset of documents from the superset collection. You can send the array of documents you want to check from superset from the client then:

1 - match all the documents in superset to the array of documents you're sending

2 - unwind your superset document array

3 - lookup the subset collections on "str_id" field and set to a field, like "subset_one_results".

4 - do a match operation on both subset results that returns an empty array on, say, "subset_one_results"... this will match all superset documents that are **not** contained in subset1 for example.

```
$match({ $and : { "subset_one_results" : { $eq : [] } }, { "subset_two_results" : { $eq : [] } } })
```

5 - group them in a new array if you want to return them as an array to the client.

To increase the performance of your operations, you have to determine how often this request will be made. If it risks being often, be sure to create an index on the field that will be solicited if it's **not** an ObjectId field. I can't tell from your code if you are using a custom string field or an ObjectId, which is why I'm bringing up this point.

I don't know what you're using for making your queries (pure MongoDB query language, driver, etc.) so I am not sure how to answer with code hence delineating the steps up above.